# Try /Except inside for loop not behaving as expected

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch

CODE :

```
def ValidateProxy(LIST_PROXIES):
    '''
    Checks if scraped proxies allow HTTPS connection
    '''

    for proxy in LIST_PROXIES:

        print('using', proxy)

        host, port = str(proxy).split(":")

        try:
            resp = requests.get('https://amazon.com', 
                                proxies=dict(https=f'socks5://{host}:{port}'),
                                timeout=6)

        except ConnectionError:
            print(proxy, 'REMOVED')
            LIST_PROXIES.remove(proxy)


    print(len(LIST_PROXIES), 'PROXIES GATHERED')

    if len(LIST_PROXIES) != 0:
        return LIST_PROXIES
    else:
        return None
```

INPUT :

```
['46.4.96.137:1080', '138.197.157.32:1080', '138.68.240.218:1080'.....] #15 proxies
```

OUTPUT :

```
using 46.4.96.137:1080
46.4.96.137:1080 REMOVED
using 138.68.240.218:1080
138.68.240.218:1080 REMOVED
using 207.154.231.213:1080
207.154.231.213:1080 REMOVED
using 198.199.120.102:1080
198.199.120.102:1080 REMOVED
using 88.198.24.108:1080
88.198.24.108:1080 REMOVED
using 188.226.141.211:1080
188.226.141.211:1080 REMOVED
using 92.222.180.156:1080
92.222.180.156:1080 REMOVED
using 183.233.183.70:1081
183.233.183.70:1081 REMOVED
7 PROXIES GATHERED # len(LIST_PROXIES) == 7, so 8 are removed which are printed above
```

MY DOUBTS :

1. Why `print('using', proxy)` is not getting executed everytime ? (becuase input list has 15 items and this line is printed only 8 times)
2. Are try and except both blocks getting executed everytime ? Becuase everytime `REMOVED` is printed on console.
3. I want to function it like `print('using', proxy)` for every proxy and if `ConnectionError` then `print(proxy, 'REMOVED')` and remove that proxy from list.

EDIT : FULL INPUT

```
['46.4.96.137:1080', '138.197.157.32:1080', '138.68.240.218:1080', '162.243.108.129:1080', '207.154.231.213:1080', '176.9.119.170:1080', '198.199.120.102:1080', '176.9.75.42:1080', '88.198.24.108:1080', '188.226.141.61:1080', '188.226.141.211:1080', '125.124.185.167:38801', '92.222.180.156:1080', '188.166.83.17:1080', '183.233.183.70:1081']
```

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exception-handling

Comment: When you say "*not as expected*" it'a always helpful to show what your expectations are based on.

Comment: @PM77-1 expectations mentioned in point 3, if still unclear, please let me know,  i will edit it

Comment: The issue looks like in your except statement you remove the item from LIST_PROXIES, but you are iterating over LIST_PROXIES so when you remove the current proxy, let's say index 0, what was at index 1 is now index 0, but your next iteration grabs the new item at index 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit 2022-08-09

I would separate the logic into two functions. Also, please follow [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) (I did not point that in the original answer)

```py
from typing import Iterable

import requests

def is_valid_proxy(proxy: str) -> bool:
    try:
        requests.get(
            'https://amazon.com',
             proxies={'https': f'socks5://{proxy}'},
             timeout=6,
        )
        return True
    except ConnectionError:
        return False


def get_valid_proxies(proxies: Iterable[str]) -> list[str]:
    return [proxy for proxy in proxies if is_valid_proxy(proxy)]
```

Instead of printing to stdout, you could use the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module.

## Original Answer

The problem is you are iterating over the `LIST_PROXIES` and removing elements from it at the same time.

If you only want to iterate over the `LIST_PROXIES` once, something like this could work:

```py
def ValidateProxy(LIST_PROXIES):
    index = 0 
    for i in range(len(LIST_PROXIES)):
        proxy = LIST_PROXIES[index]
        print('using', proxy)
        host, port = str(proxy).split(":")
        try:
            resp = requests.get('https://amazon.com', 
                                proxies=dict(https=f'socks5://{host}:{port}'),
                                timeout=6)
            index += 1
        except ConnectionError:
            print(proxy, 'REMOVED')
            LIST_PROXIES.pop(index) # Index is not incremented
    print(len(LIST_PROXIES), 'PROXIES GATHERED')
    if len(LIST_PROXIES) != 0:
        return LIST_PROXIES
    else:
        return None
```

However, if iterating over the list twice is not a problem, you can just make a copy of the list, as Sy Ker pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for this, i understood the approach but gives index out of range exception when replacing ```proxy``` with ```LIST_PROXIES[i]``` (replacing becuase proxy will be undefined) . however it can be tweaked :). And yes, creating duplicate list is very costly in this case as sizes may be very large.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. If should be `LIST_PROXIES[index]`, let met edit the post! :)

Comment: I'm not sure how my method is iterating twice over the data.

Comment: @SyKer Because, to create a copy of a list, you first have to iterate over it. Then, after the copy has been created, you have to iterate over the elements to check whether they should be eliminated or not.

Comment: seems like there is one more bug with try/except, after fixing proxy removal, all items are iterated but both try and excpet block are executed, edited question with full input

Comment: How about 'for i, value in enumerate(list)' ?

Comment: @hack3r_0m What does it mean that the both the try and except blocks are executed? The `requests.get` call will always be executed. If a `ConectionError` ocurrs, the execution will continue from the except block. However, if there is no exception, the `index` will be incremented by 1, and the except block will be skipped.

Comment: @SyKer In the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), it reads the list will be iterated. In general, every function you apply to an iterable will iterate over its elements at least once.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is  caused by the fact that you are mutating the list whilst you are still looping over it in this line.

```
LIST_PROXIES.remove(proxy)
```

This means that just before the `for` loop looks for the 'next' item in the list, the 'next' item moves left in the list and therefore is missed completely.

Check out this question/answer:
[strange result when removing item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

You are removing items from a list you are iterating over. NOT GOOD. You should iterate over a copy of the list, leaving you free to modify the original. Simply replace `for proxy in LIST_PROXIES:` with `for proxy in list(LIST_PROXIES):`